# How to insert/display div inside ngfor at particular index

Tags: html, typescript, css, angular-material, angular7

I'm using angular material to display series of images. I want to display div/component at particular index inside ngfor

```
<div #cardPicture fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="1%" fxLayoutAlign="left">
    <mat-card matTooltip="{{image.Name}}" class="card-picture" (click)="onViewDetail(image)" *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
        <img mat-card-image src="{{image.img}}">
        <div class="name">{{image.Name}}</div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
<!-- Image Detail -->
<div class="details" id="viewImageDetail">
    <app-image-detail [imageDetail]="viewImageDetail"></app-image-detail>
</div>
```

On clicking on particular image, I want to display image detail component below the image and the next row should be slide down

Comment: how are you displaying the images, in a carousel? what do you mean by 'next row should be slide down'?

Comment: It's not carousel.it's more like image gallery.

Comment: a minimal stackblitz will make it easier to help

Answer (score 0):

I could almost achieve what I wanted. Below is the change

```
<div #cardPicture fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="1%" fxLayoutAlign="left">
   <div class="imageGrid" *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
      <mat-card matTooltip="{{image.Name}}" class="card-picture" (click)="onViewDetail(image, i)">
         <img mat-card-image src="{{image.Imagebyte}}">
         <div class="name">{{image.Name}}</div>
      </mat-card>
    <div class="details" id="viewImageDetail" *ngIf="i==index">
      <app-update-image-detail [imageDetail]="viewImageDetail"></app-update-image-detail>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

If anyone has any answer, please feel free to post it